# ISR for timer on Arduino MEGA gets called only once

Tags: timers, atmega2560

I am trying to write an Arduino code to blink LED using timer 4 on Arduino MEGA (atmega2560). I resetted the timer registers, and entered all the necessary values to bring to 16MHz to 1Hz (rescalar = 1024, OCR4B = 15624), then I wrote the blinking code inside the service routine block. Now when I run the program, the ISR is called **only once**. I saw from Youtube videos that even though the setting up of TCCR registers and TIMSK is in setup() function, it repeats indefinitely like a loop. Below is my code. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

```
int led_pin = 10;
static int counter = 0;
int led_blink = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(led_pin,OUTPUT);
cli();
TCCR4A = 0;
TCCR4B = 0;
TCNT4 = 0;
OCR4B = 15625;                                //set the maximum count 16MHz -> 1Hz
TCCR4B |= (1<<CS10) | (1<<CS12) | (1<<WGM12); // prescalar = 1024 , CTC(OCR3B) mode 
TIMSK4 |= (1<<OCIE4B);
sei();
interrupts();
}


ISR(TIMER4_COMPB_vect)
{
  Serial.println(millis());
  led_blink = !led_blink;
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(led_blink == 1)
    digitalWrite(led_pin,HIGH);  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the ISR gets only called one time? With your current code the LED will only be turned on, not blinking (since you never turn it off anywhere). Do you get the Serial output in the Serial Monitor, which shows the values of `millis()`?

Comment: It's ok to set a variable and do the "heavy lifting" outside the ISR, but you got a bit side-tracked here. `digitalWrite` is very cheap, and having it in the ISR shouldn't make problems, but `Serial.println` is a very complex function that on itself uses timers and takes several ms to execute.

Comment: You can use uint8_t for the led_blink variable and it must be volatile. Otherwise compiler might optimize it out when it founds out it can't change. Also led_pin doesn't magically clear itself. It stays set forever if you don't write LOW to it...

Comment: Oh I am sorry, yes I forgot yo write the LED to low in else condition, but even after that I observed that the Serial.println(millis()) still worked only once. But out of luck when I tried to add values in both OCR4A and wrote the ISR for A register, it worked perfectly fine, even the Serial.println() worked. Can anybody please explain why? Also thank you for sharing your knowledge. I had no idea Serial.println() uses timers. Newbie things.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing an else statement in your loop:

```
else
  digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
```